# LINQ query to group strings by first letter and determine total length

Tags: c#, linq

A sequence of non-empty strings stringList is given, containing only uppercase letters of the Latin alphabet. For all strings starting with the same letter, determine their total length and obtain a sequence of strings of the form `"S-C"`, where `S` is the total length of all strings from stringList that begin with the character `C`.

```cs
var stringList = new[] { "YELLOW", "GREEN", "YIELD" }; 
var expected = new[] { "11-Y", "5-G" };
```

I tried this:

```cs
var groups =
  from word in stringList
  orderby word ascending
  group word by word[0] into groupedByFirstLetter
  orderby groupedByFirstLetter.Key descending
  select new { key = groupedByFirstLetter.Key, Words = groupedByFirstLetter.Select(x => x.Length)  };
```

But the output of this query is `Y 6 5 G 5` instead of `Y-11 G-5`.
What I would like to know is how to sum the lengths if there is more than 1 word in the group, and how to format the result/display it as expected?

Comment: start with adding `.Sum()` after you select the length. The rest should just be formatting, which could easily be another select to create the strings

Comment: `select new { key = groupedByFirstLetter.Key, Words = groupedByFirstLetter.Select(x => x.Length).Sum()  };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var results = stringList.OrderByDescending(x => x[0])
                        .ThenBy(x => x)
                        .GroupBy(x => x[0])
                        .Select(g => $"{g.Sum(x => x.Length)}-{g.Key}")
                        .ToArray();
```

Comment: This works but I got one more question. Where should I place OrderBy() and OrderByDescending() if I want the results in descending order of numerical values and when numerical values are equal in ascending order by the characters?

Comment: I have adjusted the code above. Basically just sort your set before grouping. This is mostly because the output is a string, if it was an object with a key in it, you could sort at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = stringList.GroupBy(e => e[0]).Select(e => $"{e.Sum(o => o.Length)}-{e.Key}").ToArray();
```

Not sure I am able to rewrite it in your form.